# Parent Child Identification based on character string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data set like below known as Keyword:

[image]

The output is like below:

[image]

The logic goes like this:

1. The foldercount column is nothing but the number of "/" present in the Link column
2. The Status column has only 3 values, Parent, Child and Orphan.
3. If the Link column has no '/s' present in it, the status of those keywords would be - Orphan.
4. For a particular keyword, if '/s' is present in the Link and folder count is least for that particular keyword, then it would be termed as Parent. Any other link with '/s' present would be child. Parent and child should be appended with a number which should help me identify child for which specific parent for example child1 is child of parent1. It might happen for a particular keyword, we have no child at all.

I have used the below code but it does not serve my purpose:

```
Keyword$foldercount <- str_count(Keyword$URL, "/")
Keyword$last_char <- str_sub(Keyword$URL, -3,-1)
Keyword$last_char2 <- str_sub(Keyword$URL, -2,-1)

Keyword$isParent <- ifelse(Keyword$last_char == '/s/'| Keyword$last_char2 == '/s','Parent','Child')
Keyword$isParentDerivable <- "No"
h<- grep('/s/', Keyword$URL)
Keyword$isParentDerivable[h] <- "Y"
```

Comment: Pls share `dput(Keyword)` as sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve such task with `dplyr`
Since you didnt share sample data, I have made up some example:

```
 Keyword <- data.frame(Keyword = c("shoes", "shoes", "laptop", "laptop", "orp"),
                    Link = c("www.abc.com/shoes/s/",
                                "www.abc.com/shoes/s/page=1/",
                                "www.abc.com/laptop/s/",
                                "www.abc.com/laptop/s/page2/",
                                "www.abc.com/cdcd"),
                       stringsAsFactors = F)

 library(dplyr)
 Keyword %>%
   mutate(foldercount = str_count(Link, "/")) %>%
   group_by(Keyword) %>%
   mutate(flag = ifelse(foldercount == min(foldercount), 1, 0)) %>%
   mutate(Status = ifelse(n() == 1, "Orphan", "Child")) %>%
   mutate(Status = ifelse(flag == 1 & n() > 1, "Parent", Status)) %>%
   mutate(Status = ifelse(Status != "Orphan", paste(Status, Keyword, sep = "_"), Status)) %>%
   select(-flag)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Keyword [3]
  Keyword Link                        foldercount Status       
  <chr>   <chr>                             <int> <chr>        
1 shoes   www.abc.com/shoes/s/                  3 Parent_shoes 
2 shoes   www.abc.com/shoes/s/page=1/           4 Child_shoes  
3 laptop  www.abc.com/laptop/s/                 3 Parent_laptop
4 laptop  www.abc.com/laptop/s/page2/           4 Child_laptop 
5 orp     www.abc.com/cdcd                      1 Orphan
```

You can reduce the number of steps once you understand the pipeline well.

Comment: Several `mutate` calls feel kinda "clumsy" although perhaps in this case it aids readability. One `mutate` call could be used.

Comment: This solves my purpose but since my data set is very long, it is taking forever to give the result. Is there any way of making it fast 
?